# setTimeout firing twice in this code?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So I have got this code.

```
var x = 0;

function Main() {
    console.log("window load occurred!");
    console.log('imgChild log!');
    var firstChildren = $('.imgChild');
    var arrChildren = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = firstChildren.length; i < l; i += 3) {
        arrChildren.push(firstChildren.slice(i, i + 3));
    }
    console.log(firstChildren);
    console.log(arrChildren);
    arrChildren[0].fadeIn();
    var length = arrChildren.length;

function myAnim() {
    // debugger;
    console.log('timeout log');
    console.log(x);
    arrChildren[x].animate({
        left: '-100%'
    }, function() {
        arrChildren[x].hide().animate({
            left: '0%'
        }).css('top', '0');
        x++;
        console.log(x);
        arrChildren[x].css({
            top: '0px',
            left: '100%'
        }).show().animate({
            left: '0%'
        });
        setTimeout(myAnim, 3000);
    });
}
setTimeout(myAnim, 3000);
}

$(window).on('load', Main);
```

As you can guess when window loads, the `Main` function is invoked. After creating the proper arrays it sets a timer. As the `myAnim` function is invoked the console should log like this by my logic ... `'timeout log'`, `0` (the `x`), `1` (the `x` after `x++`) and then it should move to the next timeout. However the immediately after logging `1` I see the console to log `2` as if the `x++` is done twice. Why is this happening? How can I fix it? I did some research and it turns out that sometimes the settimeout fires twice, however I cannot figure how to fix that in this case.

Comment: It fires twice because you are calling `setTimeout` twice. Assign the timeout to a variable and check if the variable is not undefined, or you could even clear the timeout it, before setting the timeout again.

Comment: Don't I fire the second `setTimeout` inside the callback function of the animate, shouldn't the second one fire after the animation is complete?

Comment: You've given no duration to your first animate. So it will fire the callback immediately.

Comment: Clear out all the extra code which doesn't effect the set timeout, and you'll see it.

Comment: The same happens with the duration. The duration does nothing but slowing the animation. As soon as it is complete it fires the callback with all of its contents immediately.